# SQLite simultaneous single & multiple column indices

Tags: sqlite, indexing

Consider the SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracer 
(
 bid INTEGER,
 sid INTEGER,
 ...
);
```

on which I typically want to run queries bearing the form

```
Q1 = SELECT * FROM tracer WHERE bid = 'bid_value';
Q2 = SELECT * FROM tracer WHERE sid = 'sid_value';
Q3 = SELECT * FROM tracer WHERE bid = 'bid_value' AND sid = 'sid_value';
```

Now suppose I have the indices

```
I1 = CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ibid ON tracer (bid);
I2 = CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS isid ON tracer (sid);
I3 = CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ibidsid ON tracer (bid,sid);
```

My understanding is that

- with query **Q1** SQLite will use index **I1**
- with query **Q2** SQLite will use index **I2**
- with query **Q3** SQLite will use index **I3**

Without index **I3** I gather that query **Q3** will run slower since the two other indices will be used sequentially to find the select result.

However, this will I imagine come at a price - inflating the size of the SQLite database file with additional indices. My question - how does one estimate the impact on size when deciding whether or not to index using `covering indices` such as **I3** above.  Some empirical testing would certainly work to give an indication as to what happens but perhaps there are more formal ways to predict such things?

I should mention that the context here is a mobile app for Android and iOS.

Do I really care about my query running a bit faster?  Not in order to present results to the user.  However, I do have concerns about how much time the app might spend when backgrounded when running a spot of SQL in response to a push notification.  I would imagine that an app that hogs too much by way of CPU resources when backgrounded is perceived as a bad citizen.  But then again there is a tradeoff - it might use less CPU thanks to its covering index but the covering index makes its memory footprint bigger?

Comment: Just for background, maybe you could let us know where you are using SQLite.  I sense that it might be in a mobile environment, where space is relatively precious.  Generally, the problem you have highlighted is a common one between performance and storage.

Comment: fair point - I have updated my post

Comment: I think without I3 sqlite will use only one index ?

Answer (score 0):

I3 is not a covering index because the query has to read the other columns.

I1 is superfluous because searches using `bid` can also be done with I3 (see the [query optimizer docs](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)).

Additional indexes need more processing when changing the table, but when you are reading a small number of rows, they probably will not affect memory usage by a noticeable amount. (But if you want to be sure, measure.)

You could consider using a [clustered index](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) if your SQLite version is modern enough (i.e., probably not on a mobile device).